# Logic Pro recording forward on Behringer X32

Tags: recording, logic, behringer

Hi I'm try to record keys on x32 via Logic Pro v10.4.8, and strange bug happened.
When I record track, its recorded little forward, and after rec I need move track little back to match with metronome and other tracks.

Comment: do you mean there is latency or a delay? How much?

Comment: So I solve this. It’s looks like latency compensation, because it place track forward. I open preferences in logic->audio just play staccato quarter notes and move slider and match latency compensation. Now it work well. Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this. This is Recording Delay in preferences->Recording->Recording delay.
That compensate to much latency. I just play stacatto quarter notes and match Recording delay to real delay.